# VBA - renaming the files

Tags: excel, vba

I have few files which, I need to change the names. I have a list of them but without the file extension.
[image]

The code will work, only if the list will have the file extensions. Any idea how to solve this issue?

```
    Sub RenameMultipleFiles()
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then
            selectDirectory = .SelectedItems(1)
            dFileList = Dir(selectDirectory & Application.PathSeparator & "*")
        
            Do Until dFileList = ""
                curRow = 0
                On Error Resume Next
                curRow = Application.Match(dFileList, Range("A:A"), 0)
                If curRow > 0 Then
                    Name selectDirectory & Application.PathSeparator & dFileList As _
                    selectDirectory & Application.PathSeparator & Cells(curRow, "B").Value
                End If
        
                dFileList = Dir
            Loop
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't or can't include the file extensions?

Comment: Hi Samuel, I have that list with the only files that need to be updated.

Comment: Ok. Can you add include the file extensions in each item of your list? That would be the simplest way to get your code working unless this cannot be done?

Comment: there are around 2 000 files, that is the reason why I am trying to find another way.

Comment: Ok. I'm testing now.

Comment: Probably your best option then is looping through the files & on each file, set the filename to a variable with the extension removed and search column A of filenames to change using match/find, then when found it, rename the file using column B list & add the extension back on. I also assume the files have multiple different extensions?

Comment: Are there different extensions involved, or only one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will *probably* produce your desired results. Please see the end for some concern with your code and use of the `On Error Resume Next`.

I have made some additions to your existing code to basically, exclude the file extension when matching the file name with the column A list and then appending the extension to the name in column B.

The code has now been edited to incorporate the `InStrRev` function to provide a dynamic result for the extension length (in a round-a-bout way).

```
 Sub RenameMultipleFiles()
 Dim CharacterCount As Long
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then
            selectDirectory = .SelectedItems(1)
            DFileList = Dir(selectDirectory & Application.PathSeparator & "*")
            Do Until DFileList = ""
                CharacterCount = InStrRev(DFileList, ".")
                curRow = 0
                On Error Resume Next
                curRow = Application.Match(Left(DFileList, CharacterCount - 1), Range("A:A"), 0)
                
                If curRow > 0 Then
                    Name selectDirectory & Application.PathSeparator & DFileList As _
                    selectDirectory & Application.PathSeparator & Cells(curRow, "B").Value & Right(DFileList, Len(DFileList) - CharacterCount + 1)
                End If
        
                DFileList = Dir
            Loop
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I have made use of the `Left(), Right() and Len()` functions.

I tested this within a test folder containing `Book.xlsx`, `Book.xls`, `Doc.doc` and `Doc.docx`.
Column A had `Book1` and `Doc1` listed.
Column B had `New_Book1` and `New_Doc1` listed.

After running the routine both files were renamed and retained their file extensions.

Worksheet:

[image: Worksheet with column A and B data]

Before running the routine:

[image: File Explorer with test files before running the routine]

After running the routine:

[image: File Explorer with test files after running the routine]

---

My concern with your code is your use of `On Error Resume Next`. The reason being if `curRow` evaluates to an error, the error is passing your `If curRow > 0 Then` as it is being ignored. This may result in unexpected or undesired results.

As you haven't declared your variables (e.g. `Dim curRow As Long`) they are implicitly delcared as type `Variant` meaning any data type can be assigned to the variable. This can also cause unexpected results, per above, you are expecting to assign numbers for your `curRow` variable however when an error is evaluated, the string `"Error 2042"` is returned to your variable which then tries to evaluate through your `If...Then` statement.

I noticed that when I was running some tests of the code, `curRow` was returning `Error 2042` which is the result of the `Match()` function returning `#N/A`. This happens when the current targeted file does not match a name in column A. As `Error 2042 > 0 = FALSE` it should return `Runtime Error 13. Type Mismatch` but due to `On Error Resume Next` it still tries to rename the file.

This would be "better" to handle rather than ignore (to avoid unexpected results from ignoring the error), such as (pseudo code):

```
If curRow = Error 2042 Then 
    'Do nothing, go to the next iteration
ElseIf curRow > 0 Then
    'Run desired code
End if
```

As the error is expected, we now handle it in this environment and allow other errors to still be thrown and/or handled if/as required.

Comment: I would `Instrrev` to find the "." because we don't know how long the extension is.

Comment: I am testing Samuel's solution but is not working for me.

Comment: @Eni, if your file extensions are not 4 characters long it probably won't work - consider incorporating `Instrrev` as suggested by Simon. My answer is a solution that will likely need some adjusting for your exact use case.

Comment: @Eni I've edited the answer to incorporate `InStrRev` along with show some testing details and elaborate on error handling. Hope it helps!